# Html wrongly encoded fetched by Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I use Nokogiri to parse an html. I need both the content and image tags in the page, so I use `inner_html` instead of `content` method. But the value returned by `content` is encoded correct, while wrongly encoded by `inner_html`. One note, the page is in Chinese and not use UTF-8 encoding.

Here is my code:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'iconv'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open("http://www.sfzt.org/advise/view.asp?id=536"), nil, 'gb18030')

doc.css('td.font_info').each do |link|
  # output, correct but not i expect: 目前市面上影响比
  puts link.content

  # output, wrong and not i expect: <img ....></img>Ŀǰ??????Ӱ??Ƚϴ?Ľ????
  # I expect: <img ....></img>目前市面上影响比
  puts link.inner_html
end
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? What version of Nokogiri? What is your expectation? When I run your above code under Ruby 1.9 I get a UTF-8 encoded string that starts with "目前市面上影响比较大的讲述《论语".

Comment: @Phrogz I use Ruby 1.9.2; If I use `link.content`, that is correct (as you mentioned above). But besides plain text, I also want to get the html tags, like img, from the page. But this this time, it is not UTF-8 encoded. It outputs something like `Ŀǰ??????Ӱ??Ƚϴ?Ľ??????????`

Comment: Please update your question showing exactly how to reproduce and verify the problem, and what you expected or desire instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is written on the 'Encoding' section on README: http://nokogiri.org/

> Strings are always stored as UTF-8 internally. Methods that return
>   text values will always return UTF-8 encoded strings. Methods that
>   return XML (like to_xml, to_html and inner_html) will return a string
>   encoded like the source document.

So, you should convert `inner_html` string manually if you want to get it as UTF-8 string:

```
puts link.inner_html.encode('utf-8') # for 1.9.x
```

Answer (score 1):

I think content strips out tags well, however the inner_html method nodes does not do this very well or at all.

"I think you can end up with some pretty weird states if you change the inner_html (which contain tags) while you are traversing. In other words, if you are traversing a node tree, you shouldn’t do anything that could add or remove nodes."

Try this:

```
doc.css('td.font_info').each do |link|
  puts link.content
  some_stuff = link.inner_html
  link.children = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(some_stuff, 'utf-8')
end
```

Comment: You may want to clarify how this addresses the question.

Comment: @Hishalv Thanks. Tried your code, the output is still wrong encoded. I wonder if I need to do some encoding converting manually.